# Converting tiles to sprite nodes in XCode Swift

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, tiles, skspritenode

I am developing a mini-game and I've drawn the map by using the program Tiled. Let's assume that I've used a tile set of three pictures; how do I 'convert' them to SKSpriteNodes? Let's say that there is one tile representing the character and three tiles representing ground. I want these four to be sprite nodes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you asking how to place these images on the screen?

Comment: No they appear on the screen when I load the tilemap. But what I am asking for is that for instance I have a character on the screen (from my tilemap.tmx file) which I want to do some stuff with such as SKActions. How can I some sort of 'convert' all unit types in to SKSpriteNodes?

Let's say that I have 1 player character and 3 monsters in my tilemap. I want them as SKSpriteNodes so I can interact with them with actions.

Comment: To mention, I've used different layers. So whenever I put the character I have named it as 'Bob' in my tilemap (using the program Tiled). Maybe this will help me but I have no clue how.

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you with the Swift version but look at the below pics to get a better understanding of what I am talking about.

**Create an Object Layer in Tiled.**

[image]

**Create objects in your map and name them.**

[image]

I assume you are using the Tiled app to create your maps. You can create an object layer for your map in the Tiled app. Once done, simply create various objects in your map. For example, create several objects called "enemy". This object layer will be read by JSTileMap and will be accessible to you in your code like this:

```
TMXObjectGroup *group = [tiledMap groupNamed:@"objectLayer"];
// make sure the you use the same groupNamed as is in your map!

NSArray *floorObjects = [group objectsNamed:@"enemy"];
    for (NSDictionary *floorObj in floorObjects)
    {
        CGFloat x = [floorObj[@"x"] floatValue];
        CGFloat y = [floorObj[@"y"] floatValue];
        CGFloat w = [floorObj[@"width"] floatValue];
        CGFloat h = [floorObj[@"height"] floatValue];

        // create your SKSpriteNode here
        // use the x, y as the node's position in the map
        // myNode.position = CGPointMake(x, y);
    }
```

Comment: Yes I am using the Tiled app :)

But I am using swift and not objective-c I have done this so far: var group = TMXObjectGroup() and later in my code I tried to assign it as: group = tileMap.groupNamed("Bob"). This crashes the app and says the following: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: I used the name Bob as the layer name for the character in the Tiled app. I don't know whether I am missing something or if I have completely misunderstood your answer as I am not familiar with objective-c

Comment: Ah I was using tile layer and not object layer! I have created an object layer now in Tiled. But how do I put my drawings from Bob tile layer to my new created object layer? I've set a box where the character is maybe that is what you've shown. Now it doesn't crash. I will try to create a sprite kit and try actions. Thank you so far I will come back with a reply soon whether it worked fully :)

Comment: @toom4ny - The object layer is only used as a position reference for nodes you are going to add yourself when the map is read in your code. For example, ladders, spikes, enemies, player starting point, etc...

Comment: Okay so the compiler will know where my new created sprite nodes in fact are or? Sorry that I am taking your time.

Another thing is how I add it as spritenode because what should I use as an argument for imageNamed when it is taken from a tileset? Or I may ask like this: The picture you have put in here has a ground with grass on it. Take that tile as a sprite node (just one of them only) how could I make that move with skactions if I can't create that tile as a spritenode (because of the argument of imageNamed)? I hope you understand what I mean

Comment: @toom4ny - I think you're a little confused on how the Tiled app works. It's gonna be a little too much to explain all of it to you here. Email me (address is on my profile page).

Comment: Hehe yeah I might be somewhat confused. Thank you alot I will send you an email :)

Comment: I've sent you an email now :)